# Salt Lake City Temple : Spires

Tags: building, design

I'm trying to plan the tops of the spires for a lego replica of the salt lake city LDS temple.  Here's a picture:
[image]

I figure I can use a [technic ball joint](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32474&C=67#T=C&C=67) for the round parts, or a [ski pole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=90540&C=85#T=C&C=85)  for the top part but I can't use them together as there's no open axle on top of the ball joint.  Is there any kind of sphere that a bar can be put through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Bar" items can fit into Technic "axle" hole. Based on that I have couple of options. Both are similar to Technic ball joint you've found, but have holes on both ends.

[Technic Ball Joint with Through Axle Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=53585#T=C).

[image]

[Technic Ball with Grooves](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2907#T=C)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'll suggest using [15395 2x2 dome bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15395) and [553 2x2 dome top](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=553c). The dome top has a stud with hole on its end, which makes it very easy to place a ski pole, or a 1x2 plate to support a minifig:

[image: LeoCAD diagram of assemblies using 2x2 dome]

There's downsides to this approach, though:

- The shape of the domes is not entirely round
- The 2x2 bottom dome *in light grey* colour is quite rare, and therefore relatively expensive in the aftermarket.

---

Another option is to use [44358 3x3 ball turret socket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44358) and [44359 3x3 ball turret](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44359). These have been used as cannons in several Star Wars sets and should be easy to find.

The 3x3 ball turret provides an axle on top - in order to provide a stud for supporting a minifig, you may modify a [6587 3L axle with stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6587), cutting it down to 1L so it fits flush within the top part of the ball turret. I know cutting down parts is frowned upon by purists; and fitting the axle flush may make it hard to get it out.

[image: LeoCAD diagram of assemblies using 3x3 ball turret]